# Is it possible to edit the filter labels in Quicksight?

Tags: filter, label, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to edit what shows as the filter label in a dashboard in Quicksight so that it doesn't just show the value in the database but a custom label?  I am trying to make it easier for people who are not familiar with a bunch of course codes to read and interpret the data, and compare courses across different program streams.

I have a bunch of unique course codes in a database, but the course names are similar.  For example, a course labelled "Introduction to Statistics" may be offered by different programs in different locations, but each has a unique course ID which is stored in the database.  I can use this course ID to filter, but that requires anyone reviewing the data to know what all the course codes are.  I would like to use the course code to filter the data, but in the interactive filter that people will see and use a custom label, not the course code.

Eg.
Course code = 1701, label that appears in filter is "Stats 101, Psychology"

Course Code = 1801, label that appears in filter is "Stats 101, Economics"

Course code = 3300, label that appears in filter is "Advanced Statistics, Health Sciences"

I have looked at various controls on the filters and labelling, but I can't seem to find an option which will allow me to edit the value labels.

Is it feasible to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Linda